# firebase functions access data of another collections

Tags: key

I'm looking to access data from anothers collections. I'm using Firebase Functions with event `onWrite`, I'm tried to use `event.data.ref.parent` or `admin.database().ref` but the result is a JSON with diferent result of I spected.

Example of return:

[image: Example of return]

I want a return like this:

```
 { asuhqeuwhiqeuq: { name: 'alex', age: 15 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my question

the solution is:

```
var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref('/ColletionHere/' + IdFromObject);
ref.once('value')
 .then(function(snapshot) {
  console.log( "snap " + snapshot.key );
});
```